# Reinstall default apps on Galaxy S3 before updating to Jelly Bean

Tags: updates, 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-s-3, samsung-kies

I want to update my Galaxy S3 to Jelly Bean but after downloading the firmware using Kies, it starts updating, but then it stops with a "dead" Android with a red triangle icon.

I think it's because I have removed some default apps like ChatOn and Yahoo widgets.

Is there any way to get them back or to install the official Jelly Bean update without a factory reset? I don't want to reinstall my apps again and lose my settings each time I need to update the OS (I also don't want bloatware apps that are pre-installed).

**EDIT:**
I have ClockWorkMod recovery installed. I think that might be the problem. Is there any way I can flash the stock recovery only?.
My operator is vodafone from Portugal.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm afraid with most major upgrades (i.e. if the Android version "changed its name", and not just the 3rd digit gets bumped like e.g. 2.3.3 to 2.3.4) a factory reset will go along.

Comment: Building on @Izzy 's statement, that isn't frequent enough to be a deal-breaker as far as I am concerned (although inconvenient).  It is slightly inconvenient, but it does allow for everything to be clean for the new release since JB focused on being smooth.  Another option would be to root and use Titanium Backup to backup apps+data.

Comment: As the OP remarked the updated might have failed due to "removed some default apps", I guess the device in question is already rooted. The current problem most likely is the device no longer booting up ("red triangle"), so a TB backup cannot be performed (@Bruno-P: Maybe you could clearify this).

Comment: Is the device is already rooted. I can boot it. i just cant install the update.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what network you are on the official OTA update may be your easiest answer. When I updated my razr m  from ICS to JB 4.1 on verizon with the offical JB OTA update, none of my data was lost, didn't have to reload any apps, or reset options.

Also when you clear your user data your phone may automatically re-download apps that you previously had. In my case when I cleared my user data to root my phone, it re-downloaded all the apps I had before the clear but unfortunately the options for the apps were reset.

You may want to try clearing only your cache first (that will not erase any contacts or apps) and try reinstall again.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not disable but uninstall system ROM apps, resetting won't make any difference. You need to download a stock rom (try sammobile for instance) and flash it via odin.

This is the best method I recommend. Get the DBT (germany) rom as it has no bloatware. Also, avoid using KIES to update. Really untrustworthy.